# Проблема с Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer

Tags: java, android

Есть 8-ми битная картинка, заполненная черным цветом то есть нулями. HEX-редактор это подтверждает — все нули. Когда загружаю ее в `ByteBuffer`, в нем видимо мусор, значения прыгают `0` или `255` через раз.

Вот часть кода:

```
try {
    // получаем входной поток
    InputStream ims = context.getAssets().open("heightMap/cj.bmp");
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        Log.d("Terrain", bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        heigthMap = byteBuffer.array();
        for (byte b: heigthMap) Log.d("Terrain", "b = " + (b & 0xFF));
    } else {
        draw = false;
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    draw = false;
} finally {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

Что я не знаю или не понимаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно у вас Bitmap представлен в виде [ARGB_8888](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html), то есть Alpha/Red/Green/Blue или непрозрачность/красный/зелёный/синий. При этом хотя у вас красный/зелёный/синий нули, но непрозрачность 255 (пиксели полностью непрозрачные). Скорее всего вы наблюдаете что-то типа

```
b = 0
b = 0
b = 0
b = 255
b = 0
b = 0
b = 0
b = 255
...
```

В исходном файле цвет 24-битный (просто RGB), но при загрузке в память `BitmapFactory` преобразовал его в 32-битный ARGB. Чтобы убедиться в этом, проверьте [`Bitmap.getConfig()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getConfig%28%29).

Comment: Верно ARGB_8888, как мне заставить его быть просто 8 бит?

Comment: @CJ1, вы хотите, чтобы в ByteBuffer у вас было по три байта на цвет? Это можно сделать вручную (если сильно надо, я набросаю код). Но зачем вам это может пригодиться? Сейчас вы можете вычитывать целый цвет через `byteBuffer.getInt(offset)`, например, у вас в одной int-переменной будет весь цвет. А так вы замаетесь по три байта объединять (трёхбайтового типа-то нет). Если вы хотите сделать манипуляции с отдельным компонентами, просто пропускайте эти альфа-байты (например, ищите нужный пиксель по `(y*width+x)*4`). Всё равно для обратной записи в `Bitmap` они нужны будут.

Comment: Понятно, в любом случае будет приходить по 4 байта, но я сам смогу конечно как надо перевести, думал есть способ обработать изображение максимально просто, спасибо, все понятно.